# How to listen for horizontal or vertical Drag after OnLongpress - flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a widget wrapped with GestureDetector, when the user holds the widget the onLongPress method will trigger some function and onLongPressUp will stop the function. the problem is I need to detect when the user drags their finger horizontally or vertically after the onLonPress is triggered. apparently the code doesn't listen for onVerticalDrag or onHorizontalDrag after OnLongPress is triggered. Is there any way to listen for onLongPress and onHorizontalDrag Simultaneously?

Comment: Possibly you need to use NotificationListener or Draggable Widget

Comment: Draggable widget doesn't work correctly, i will try with NotificationListener